# I want to disable edit button for next 24 hours when it is updated in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to disbale button for specific work for next 24 hours when that user click that button. also i want   user can't edit any thing after 24 hours [image]24 hours.

```
  <?php $i = 0; ?>
        @foreach ($works as $work)
            @php
                $start =Carbon\Carbon::parse($work->start_from)->format('d-m-Y h:i A');
                $end  =Carbon\Carbon::parse($work->end_to)->format('d-m-Y h:i A');
                $t1 = strtotime($start);
                $t2 = strtotime($end);
                $total = gmdate('h:i',$t2 - $t1);
                 $oneHourDiff = now()->addDays(-1);

            @endphp
            <tr>
                <?php $i++; ?>
                <td>{{ $i }}</td>
                <td>{{$start}}</td>
                <td>{{$end}}</td>
                <td>{{$total}}</td>
                <td>{{$work->project->Name}}</td>
                <td>{{ $work->description }}</td>
                @if(isset($work->user->name))
                    <td>{{$work->user->name}}</td>
                @else
                    <td>--</td>
                @endif
                <td>
                    @can('edit_work')
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm " data-toggle="modal"
                                    data-target="#edit{{ $work->id }}"
                                    title="{{ trans('Works_trans.Edit') }}"><i
                                    class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                            </button>

                    @endcan
                    @can('delete_work')
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm " data-toggle="modal"
                                data-target="#delete{{ $work->id }}"
                                title="{{ trans('Works_trans.Delete') }}"><i
                                class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
                    @endcan
                </td>
            </tr>

    @endforeach
```

I want to disbale button for specific work for next after 24 hour when that user click that button. also i want   user can't edit any thing after 24 hour

Comment: Are you changing anything in database after user clicks this button?

Comment: no i  assign to delete and edit button it make disable on it

Comment: Are you open modal on click ? if you are open url on click the disable button is false because the user has open the edit page by passing an id can you think this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `updated_at` column in your database table, then you can get the last updated time from that column and compare it with the current time. So, if it is less than 24 hours, then you can disable it.

If you have multiple users, you will have to create an additional table, to keep a record of the edited time and the user ID. From that table, compare the time and enable/disable the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You have two consitions here:

1. Disable once edited (for 24 hours)
2. Do not edit once 24 hours have passed.

What you want to do here is offcourse ignore the first condition and do this:

Check if `created_at` is not equal to `updated_at` disable edit button or `created_ad` is more than 24 hours ago disable edit.

```
$created_at = Carbon::create($record->created_at);
$now = Carbon::now();
$time_passed = $now->diffInHours($created_at);

if($record->created_at != $record->updated_at || $time_passed > 24){
    //Disable the edit button
    //...
}
```

These 2 conditions will make sure the record does not get edit twice as well as editing is disabled after 24 hours. So basically you are allowing to edit only once and in first 24 hours only.